# How can I get an autosaving react-hook-form to work with controlled inputs?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, forms, react-hook-form

I am writing a planning form application which presents users with a set of planning forms which contain questions for them to plan their event. These questions come in different "types" such as "textbox", "checkbox", etc. Some of these types are going to be custom form widgets which are not existing HTML input types.

This application uses React.js with react-hook-form for the forms. The app is supposed to "autosave" such that any time a form input is altered, it buffers for around a second waiting for input to stop, and then if input has not been submitted for the full second, it posts to the api.

To try and make this work, I have created a custom hook to facilitate this behavior:

```
import _ from "lodash";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { useCallback } from "react";
import useMockApi from "./useMockAPI";


export default function usePlanningForm() {
    const { getFormData, postQuestions } = useMockApi();
    const defaultValues = getFormData();

    const { formState, register, getValues, reset, control } = useForm({ defaultValues });
    const { dirtyFields } = formState;
    const debouncedSubmit = useCallback(
        _.debounce(async (data: any) => {
            if (Object.keys(dirtyFields).length == 0) return;

            // Only submit the dirty fields
            const dirtyData = Object.keys(dirtyFields).reduce((acc: any, key) => {
                acc[key] = data[key];
                return acc;
            }, {});
            //! This is where the questions post to the API
            postQuestions(dirtyData);
            reset(data, {
                keepValues: true,
            });
        }, 1000),
        [dirtyFields]
    );
    const onChange = async () => {
        const currValues = getValues();
        await debouncedSubmit(currValues);
    };

    return {
        onChange,
        register: register,
        isDirty: formState.isDirty,
        control,
    };
}
```

Additionally, I have the following App.tsx which demonstrates the way that I use it in my application (this is only a demo of the full app):

```
import { Control, Controller, UseFormRegister } from "react-hook-form";
import "./App.css";
import AutosaveIndicator from "./components/AutosaveIndicator";
import usePlanningForm from "./hooks/useAutosaveForm";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
    const { onChange, register, isDirty, control } = usePlanningForm();
    const autosaveStatus = isDirty ? "Saving" : "Saved";

    return (
        <>
            <h1>Autosaving Form w/ Custom Widgets</h1>

            <AutosaveIndicator status={autosaveStatus} />
            <div className="card">
                <form onChange={onChange}>
                    <TextInput name="q1" register={register} />
                    <CheckboxInput name="q2" checkboxes={["checkbox1", "checkbox2"]} register={register} />
                    <AppendableListQuestion question={{ id: "q3" }} control={control} />
                </form>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}

interface TextInputProps {
    name: string;
    register: UseFormRegister<any>;
}
function TextInput({ name, register }: TextInputProps) {
    return (
<>
            <label htmlFor={name}>{name}</label>
            <input {...register(name)} />
    
</>    );
}

interface CheckboxInputProps {
    name: string;
    checkboxes: string[];
    register: UseFormRegister<any>;
}
function CheckboxInput({ checkboxes, name, register }: CheckboxInputProps) {
    return (
        <fieldset>
            <legend>{name}</legend>
            {checkboxes.map((checkbox) => (
                <div key={checkbox}>
                    <input type="checkbox" value={checkbox} {...register(name)} />
                    <label>{checkbox}</label>
                </div>
            ))}
        </fieldset>
    );
}

interface AppendableListQuestionProps {
    question: {
        id: string;
    };
    control: Control;
}
function AppendableListQuestion({ question, control }: AppendableListQuestionProps) {
    const { id } = question;

    return (
        <Controller
            name={id.toString()}
            control={control}
            render={({ field: { onChange, value, } }) => (
                <AppendableList items={value} onChange={onChange} />
            )}
        />
    );
}

interface AppendableListProps {
    items: string[];
    onChange: (
        items: string[]
    ) => void;
}
function AppendableList({ items, onChange }: AppendableListProps) {
    if (!items) {
        items = [];
    }
    const [adderValue, setAdderValue] = useState("");

    // Add an item to the list when the button is clicked
    function addItem() {
        if (adderValue === "") return;
        const newItem = adderValue;
        const newList = [...items, newItem];
        onChange(newList);
        setAdderValue("");
    }

    function removeItem(value: string) {
        const newList = items.filter((item) => item !== value);
        onChange(newList);
    }

    // Update the value of the adder input
    function onChangeAdderValue(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
        setAdderValue(e.target.value);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Add..." onChange={onChangeAdderValue} value={adderValue}/>
                <button type="button" onClick={addItem}>+</button>
            </div>
            <ul>
                {items.map((value) => (
                    <li key={value}>
                        {value}
                        <button type="button" onClick={() => removeItem(value)}>-</button>
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
            <input type="hidden" disabled />
        </div>
    );
}
```

This code can be pulled and interacted with at https://github.com/njrardin/autosave-custom-widgets

My issue is that while the uncontrolled components (the textbox and checkbox) behave appropriately, I have some components (such as the `AppendableList` which must be controlled because there's no good way to facilitate their behavior in an uncontrolled manner. What I want to happen is when the user adds/removes an item from the `AppendableList`, it should trigger the `onChange` function from `useAutosaveForm` the same way it does when I change the value of one of the uncontrolled question types.

Currently, it triggers the `onChange` when the user edits the "Add..." field of `AppendableList`. This is not supposed to occur. Additionally, it does not properly instigate a submission when the user adds or removes an item from the list. Instead, it either freezes in a "saving" state, or it posts a list with one item missing.